# Get position of streetview pegman before he is dropped

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm usually pretty handy with the google maps API, but I'm stumped on this problem. Does anybody know of a way to get the exact latlng of the pegman before you have dropped him (the red circle in the picture below).

I want to know because I want to change the heading of the panorama that will open to be at the point where the pegman was dropped so the view will be "looking at" the area the pegman was dropped.

[image]